# stop modal exceeding browser limits

Tags: html, css

I have a modal that I maintain an aspect ration of 16:9. It works well on most screens but of some if the browser is considerable wider than the height the modal streches above and below the browser.

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/gp6pbpov/). If you make the output panel wider the red modal exeeds the limits.

I would like to have the modal stop getting bigger when it reaches the top of the browser. I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

```
<div class="modal">
    Aspect is kept.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 9 / 16);
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: there was a small bug in my answer which I've fixed it now. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your css to this -

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 80vw; /* Use 80% of viewport width */
    height: 45vw; /* use 45% of viewport Width so 16:9 ratio */
    max-height: 100vh; /* limits the height to not exceed viewport height */
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp6pbpov/3/)

**UPDATE:** Fixed the 16:9 ratio bug on higher viewport size.
In the earlier fiddle the width keeps on increasing when the height reached its limit. To resolve this, add this line of css -

```
max-width: calc(100vh * 16/9);
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp6pbpov/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The modal is actually not 16:9 in your example. If you change the padding-bottom to `calc(80% * 9 / 16);` it will be.

Aside from that I would try the vw/max-height solution proposed by Rohit.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution that uses `vmin` to keep the modal from exceeding the boundaries of the window. An advantage of this solution is that it preserves the aspect ratio of your modal no matter how the window is resized.

```css
.modal {
    position: relative;
    top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90vmin;
    height: 63vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    Aspect is kept.
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/gp6pbpov/2/

Comment: I try avoid using translateY(-50%), it can cause a slight blurring on some browsers.

Comment: @KeithPower Interesting, I just did some research on that, thanks. For future readers: `This is because you're landing on a half-pixel. Let's say your height is 200px and the element you're trying to vertical align is 100px - no problem here, it'll align perfectly. However, if the height of your element is 101px, you'll land on a .5 pixel value, making text and icons blurry.` - [from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/2z9ub7/css3_translatey_in_webkit_browsers_makes_text/cph6nwe).